# "user lacks privilege or object not found" when executing sql script from spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit, spring-test

I am using Hibernate 3 and Spring 3. I have been trying to populate an in memory database, and I am using Spring to do so. When I try to do this, I am getting lots of frustration, and this stack trace: To save you guys some reading, the exception  is:

```
user lacks privilege or object not found: XFC_ACTIONSTARTCONDITIONTYPE  

Failed to execute database script; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement at line 1 of resource class path resource [ctl_data-scrubd.sql]: INSERT INTO xfc_ActionStartConditionType (actionStartConditionTypeId,actionStartConditionTypeName) VALUES (&apos;1&apos;,&apos;Start After Action Completed&apos;)" type="org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException">org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Failed to execute database script; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement at line 1 of resource class path resource [ctl_data-scrubd.sql]: INSERT INTO xfc_ActionStartConditionType (actionStartConditionTypeId,actionStartConditionTypeName) VALUES (&apos;1&apos;,&apos;Start After Action Completed&apos;)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:57)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory.initDatabase(EmbeddedDatabaseFactory.java:136)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory.getDatabase(EmbeddedDatabaseFactory.java:111)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder.build(EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder.java:113)
at com.capitaliq.loader.persistence.PersistenceHelper.setUpSessionFactory(PersistenceHelper.java:123)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement at line 1 of resource class path resource [ctl_data-scrubd.sql]: INSERT INTO xfc_ActionStartConditionType (actionStartConditionTypeId,actionStartConditionTypeName) VALUES (&apos;1&apos;,&apos;Start After Action Completed&apos;)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.executeSqlScript(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:198)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:132)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:45)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: user lacks privilege or object not found: XFC_ACTIONSTARTCONDITIONTYPE
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.executeSqlScript(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:184)
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: XFC_ACTIONSTARTCONDITIONTYPE
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.SchemaManager.getTable(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readTableName(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDML.compileInsertStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatements(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
```

I tentatively want to say my problem is the tables are not being created, but I am not sure. I have followed all the directions about creating a database, and every combination under the sun will not work. 
Here is my context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans default-lazy-init="true" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd">
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>


<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">    <!---->
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:mydb;create=true"/>
    <property name="username" value="sa"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>

</bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="configLocation" value="hibernate.cfg.xml.incDTD"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.shutdown">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<!--    <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource" enabled="#{systemProperties.INITIALIZE_DATABASE}" ignore-failures="ALL">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:ctl_data-scrubd.sql" />
</jdbc:initialize-database>-->




<bean id="dataSourceInitializer" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="databasePopulator">
        <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator">
            <property name="sqlScriptEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
            <property name="scripts">
                <list>
                    <value>classpath:ctl_data-scrubd.sql</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

All i want to do is use the script file to populate this database. Don't say that my sql is wrong, because I know for a fact it isn't. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Which version of HSQLDB are you using?

Comment: @Alex, from MANIFEST.MF: Specification-Version: 2.0.1-rc2
Specification-Vendor: The HSQL Development Group
Implementation-Title: Standard runtime
Implementation-Version: 2.0.1-rc2
Implementation-Vendor: The HSQL Development Group
So version 2.0.1-rc2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chalking this one up as a mystery of the universe; I never did get this to work. Just redid the way I was populating my tables.

Answer (score 0):

You must explicitly define the name of the column with the @Column annotation.

Example

```
@Column(name = "column-name")
private String domainName;
```

In "column-name" you must replace with the name set in your initial script and should not be in CamelCase. And the "domainName" is the attribute name inside your app.

Regards